# While using azure OCR as a web service, if I know the orientation of text, what param should I use?

Tags: azure, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Microsoft Azure OCR web service. When I use flag "detectOrientation" as true, sometimes it gives weird result. (Tries to identify vertical text, even though I want it to read horizontal text) So, I want to set my orientation as I know it as "Up". Even if I set "detectOrientation" as false, it returns same result.

Surprisingly, if I use Microsoft demo page, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/, it is returning correct result. Might be it is doing some pre/post processing or adding some flags. But, it is not revealing this information. Reported this issue so many times to Microsoft but no reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the orientation manually as the parameter `detectOrientation` is a boolean (true/false) as stated [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc)

The response from the [demo](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) page is not the result of the Computer Vision API's [**OCR**](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc), it is the result of using the Computer Vision API's [**Recognize Text**](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200) then [Get **Recognize Text** Operation Result](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2cf1154055056008f201) to get the result of the operation.

The response of the **OCR** includes following:

- textAngle
- orientation
- language
- regions
- lines
- words
- boundingBox
- text

While the response from the Get **Recognize Text** Operation Result includes the following:

- Status Code
- Lines
- Words
- BoundingBox
- Text

If you compare the results of the demo page you'll find that they match the Recognize Text, not the OCR.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the **detect Orientation** parameter **just** detects the orientation of all the text in the image, it is **not an actual setting** that lets you choose which text to read based on its orientation like you're trying to use it.

Comment: Try to put your question in comments instead of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Surprisingly, if I use Microsoft demo page,
> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/,
> it is returning correct result.

On the demo page, as stated, they don't use `OCR` operation of the Web service but the new `Recognise Text` API operation.

Switch to this one, and your results will be consistent.

And to answer your other question about passing the orientation, no there is no such parameter.