# Using Azure, is there a way I can detect text orientation?

Tags: python, azure, ocr, orientation

I'm currently using the Auzre Vision API through Python like so:

```py
import azure.ai.vision as vision

service_options = vision.VisionServiceOptions(
    os.environ["PAY_VISION_ENDPOINT"], os.environ["AZURE_PAY_VISION_KEY"]
)

vision_source = vision.VisionSource(filename=str(image_path))

analysis_options = vision.ImageAnalysisOptions()
analysis_options.features = vision.ImageAnalysisFeature.TEXT
analysis_options.language = "en"

image_analyzer = vision.ImageAnalyzer(
    service_options, vision_source, analysis_options
)

result = image_analyzer.analyze()
```

In the result set, I see a bounding box, but it always starts in the top left, so I can't use that to detect orientation. I don't see any other way to get orientation. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51058659/while-using-azure-ocr-as-a-web-service-if-i-know-the-orientation-of-text-what) question, but that just points out that I should be able to see orientation, but not set it. However, when I try the [sample](https://portal.vision.cognitive.azure.com/demo/extract-text-from-images), I don't see orientation.

The documentation from MS ([here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/python/ComputerVision/REST/python-print-text.md) and [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc)) indicates that I should be able to get this information via a `detectOrientation` property, which I've tried setting as `analysis_options.detectOrientation = "true"`, but that doesn't change the response. I'm clearly missing something.

How can I get the orientation of the text like it seems I should be able to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.ai.vision.imageanalysis.models.imageanalysisoptions?view=azure-java-preview),  It looks like there might be a confusion in the usage of the Azure Vision API. The `detectOrientation` property is not part of the `ImageAnalysisOptions` in the `azure.ai.vision`.

You get the orientation, you can check [OCR result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/computervision/recognize-printed-text/recognize-printed-text?view=rest-computervision-v3.1&tabs=HTTP#code-try-0),

```bash
https://<Endpoint_Name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.1/ocr?detectOrientation=True
```

With above request, I able to get orientation and angle.
[image]

You can also check [document intelligence's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/quickstarts/get-started-sdks-rest-api?view=doc-intel-4.0.0&preserve-view=true&pivots=programming-language-python) [layout model](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/rest/FormRecognizer/how-to-guide/layout-model-output.json) that also gives `angle` output.